# Checking which users and groups has access to folder and get there user name

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using the following rest end point while trying to get user name and there permission levels for a particular Folder.

I am getting the users name that are in the group, but I am not getting their names whom I have given permission explicitly to the folder level permission. What should be the rest end point for it

The end point I am using:

```
/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents/Document.docx')/ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments?$expand=Member,Member/Users,RoleDefinitionBindings
```